# How to extract month from a date in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to extract a month from a date in SAS, but so far all my new month variables are coming up as missing.

I have attempted to use some combinations of the month() function in SAS, but so far it just comes up as missing. The dates are formatted as follows: 01/31/2017 (MMDDYY10.)

I have tried

```
month = month(end_date) 

Month =catx('/',put(month(end_date),z2
```

I would like the Month to show up as a number (01) or a 3 letter code (JAN), currently it is just missing (.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your first example is returning a missing value I would assume `end_date` is not formatted correctly. What does the variable look like when if you run `proc contents` on the data set?

Comment: It shows up as a Num type with a format of MMDDYY10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `month()` to return a missing value the `end_date` variable must be numeric and missing.  If end_date were a character variable the log would show `invalid numeric data`.

Use the `monname3.` format to convert a date value to a $3. character value *mon*

```
monthname = put (end_date, monname3.);
```

Other alternatives are:

- keep the date value unchanged and change the format, or
- map the date value to the first of the month value and also format that

For example:

```
end_date_copy = end_date;
format end_date_copy monname3.;

end_date_month = intnx('month', end_date, 0);
format end_date_month monname3.;
```

What you ultimately do depends on how the *mon* is to be used downstream in reporting or aggregating.